# Nginx - Cached Welcome page on domain

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, cache

I have an interesting issue. So I installed nginx to try it out and now I'm regretting it. The initial setup wasn't bad, but once I removed nginx and rebuilt the server (it was a clean install to begin with) I'm still getting the welcome page. I thought that maybe I missed something since it was a linode rebuild.

I also shut the server down to see if it still responded and it did. I'm not sure how to clear this, but it's extremely frustrating since I can't get to the Apache2 virtual domain as this overrides it.

So here is the curl.

```
user@localhost:~# curl -l ip
curl: (7) Failed to connect to [ip] port 80: Connection refused


user@localhost:~# curl -l www.domain.com
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've shut the machine down and it's *still* answering, then the problem isn't the machine, it's something upstream.  I'm thinking either your DNS is pointing to somewhere else, or you've got a rather aggressive caching proxy between you and the far end.